# Hide invitation to create tag wiki if the user can't edit it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki

I think there is no point in inviting the user to create the wiki page if the user doesn't meet the criteria to create the wiki in first place:

[image: yes I do]

But then:

[image: what?]

Ouch...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but how else can you learn the rules for the tag wiki creation -- or that it exists at all -- without following that link in the first place?

Comment: mmhh probably you'll eventually do, when you have enough rep on the given tag?

Comment: What about `The XX tag has no wiki, read here what is required to help creating it`?

Comment: I saw the tag wiki "invite" this morning, for the first time, on SF. I clicked around for a bit until I hit a tag wiki for which I met the editing requirements. It seemed a bit counter-intuitive...  Perhaps a scale/number/anything indicating a user's proximity to tag-wiki-editor capability, for the specific tag wiki they're viewing? I thought I was just missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Completed, any registered user can suggest an edit for any tag wiki.

There is an edge case where anonymous are invited yet can not edit, but that is by design, if they dislike this they can register.